# Random UIButton position in a Quiz

Tags: button, random

How to change randomly position of four UIButtons (quiz answers) in xcode 5, iOS 7 ?

I would like to change the position of the buttons (answers) each time the new question loads.
Compatibility with iPhone 4 and 5 should be given.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the position of any object as follows

```
    CGRect rect = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(rand()%(int)rect.size.width, rand()%(int)rect.size.height);
    myButton.center = point;
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(point));
```

I hope this helps

e